MacBook Air webcam (FacetimeHD) not working after upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
I own a MacBook Air 2017, and the webcam worked fine running FacetimeHD/0.1 driver (factimehd-DKMS) on 22.04 LTS.
In order to proceed with the automatic upgrade to 24.04 LTS (on Aug 29, 2024... tadum-dum du-dum), I needed to remove that DKMS driver. Upgrade was successful after that.
Now, I can't reinstall the webcam's driver. There seems to be a problem with broadcom-sat dkms, for which I have two kernels running:

broadcom-sta/6.30.223.271, 6.8.0-40-generic, x86_64: installed
broadcom-sta/6.30.223.271, 6.8.0-41-generic, x86_64: installed

I did uninstall them to see if they could clear the way for facetimehd-dkms, but all I got was cold sweat from not having Wifi connection. I promptly reinstalled them.
Whatever I do, I get a variation of the following:
> Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 6.8.0-41-generic (x86_64)
> Consult /var/lib/dkms/facetimehd/0.1/build/make.log for more information.
> dpkg: error processing package facetimehd-dkms (--configure):
> installed facetimehd-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
> Errors were encountered while processing: facetimehd-dkms
> E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Has anyone else run into this?
Not sure if it's related: I noticed in other posts that some people had trouble reinstalling their in-built webcam on non-Mac devices after upgrading to 24.04 LTS.

I found the solution (if installing FacetimeHD for the first  time, skip to B).
A) CLEANUP
If you're getting the same type of error I did, make sure you remove facetimeHD-dkms entirely. Check by typing in the Konsole:
sudo apt-get purge facetimehd-dkms

Then check it's gone by typing:
sudo dkms status

B) (RE)INSTALLATION
FacetimeHD for Debian
You're welcome.
